# Use control from Expression Blend in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, expression-blend

I know that I can open my `WPF` app in `VS` and `Expression Blend` at thee same time and work it.
If I change color button in EB, VS refresh project and that's work's fine.

My question is: Can I make simple button in `Expression Blend` (not all application just button) and use it in a different `Visual Studio WPF` project? How can I do this?

Comment: Yes. You just copy the code across to your project - or put it in a utility assembly that any project can call.

Comment: hm i don't understand could you explein on simple esample? I mean I create new WPF project in EB, then I open VS and create other project... what I should copy?

Comment: You need to copy the template for the button design. I don't have Expression installed on this machine so I can't double check the steps. See http://expressioniq.com/?p=60 for a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should be your answer, actually when in WPF , WP or W8 you create a control the simple way to do very thing is to right click over it and click on "MakeIntoUserControl". As you click over it the option you would notice that it would create respective file of UserControl.xaml. In Expression Blend you need to build the project so that things may go fine. The very UserControl you made would now appear in the assets as you type the name of the UserControl.

Build the project again and Right click over project and click on "Edit in Visual Studio"
Now  as you go to Visual Studio , you will notice that same user control would be there with same name.

[image: Cutsom User Control in Blend]

[image: In VS]

I hope it does the job for you.

Regards.